# Signed Cookies in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to get data from `Amazon CloudFront` which should be secured by `Signed Cookies` in Angular. How we think it should work:

1. I ask backend for cookies on url `https://api2.site.com/app/signer` and I got this:
   [HTTP request cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsd8.png)

- Cookie domain is `site.com`

2. I ask for the file from CloudFront by HTTP GET from URL `https://live-test.site.com/05687be5-bd5c-4497-9f7a-d10e8b8159bd/live.m3u8`. But in this step I don't see any cookies in request and the message from CloudFront is `Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value`.

I also somewhere read that I must use `withCredential` in HTTP request so I added this to `HTTP Interceptor`:

```
          request.url.includes('live-test.site.com')
            ? request.clone({
                withCredentials: true,
                setHeaders: { Authorization: idToken },
              })
            : request.clone({
                setHeaders: { Authorization: idToken },
              }),
        ),
```

Do you have any ideas how to make it work?